# Dynamic links / universal links not working in cold start

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-dynamic-links, swift5, ios-universal-links

I use firebase dynamic links. They work perfectly fine when the app is in background and I use the `application continue userActivity` function. 
However if I click on a dynamic link and cold start the application (not running in background) then not only does the `application continue userActivity` not run, when I breakpoint at `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`, I try to print `launchOptions` and it returns `nil`.

I setup the dynamic links exactly like the documentation describes.

In the associated domains - I have `applinks:*******.page.link` and under URL Types I created one with the identifier `*******.page.link` and the URL scheme as my Bundle identifier.

In `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` - before `FirebaseApp.configure()` , I do (as instructed from a similar question I found about universal linking) `FirebaseOptions.defaultOptions()?.deepLinkURLScheme = org.*******.*****`

Comment: Have you solved the problem? I am facing the same issue...

Comment: @Marceeelll
Didn't solve it, however there should be new info online about the topic because this was a couple of months back and very new.

Answer (score 1):

To receive the Firebase Dynamic Links that you created, you must include the Dynamic Links SDK in your app and call the handleUniversalLink: and dynamicLinkFromCustomSchemeURL: methods when your app loads to get the data passed in the Dynamic Link.

[Visit for more detail](https://firebase.google.com/docs/dynamic-links/ios/receive?hl=en)